# Sitecore XP0 9.1 Upgrade from 9 update 2 Issues

Tags: xconnect

I am unable to start the xconnect related services `Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer`, `Sitecore Processing Service` and `Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine` after xconnect upgrade. Getting an error from event viewer while starting `Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer` is :

> Application: XConnectSearchIndexer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName,
>   System.String, System.Security.Policy.Evidence,
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark
>   ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName,
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly,
>   System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef, IntPtr, Boolean, Boolean,
>   Boolean)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)    at
>   Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader.LoadConfigurationAssemblies()
>   at
>   Serilog.Settings.Configuration.ConfigurationReader..ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContext)    at
>   Serilog.ConfigurationLoggerConfigurationExtensions.ConfigurationSection(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSettingsConfiguration,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContext)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Logging.Serilog.LoggerConfigurationExtensions.RegisterLoggerFromConfiguration(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
>   at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Logging.Start(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration,
>   System.String)    at
>   Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.InitializeConfigurationAndRun(System.Action)
>   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Program.Main(System.String[])

Any advices?

Comment: which SOLR version do you have?

Comment: This might be a .Net compatibility issue. Correct version should be .Net 4.6.2 or 4.7 - please see compatibility table here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164  You could also try repairing .Net framework and see if that helps. Best Regards.

Comment: @Sitecore Sam : Solr 7.2.1

Comment: @JustinBradley: My machine already has 4.7 version

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue: System event viewer was only giving me the exact information you presented. I tried running maengine.exe manually and received a little bit more details of the error:

"Operation is not supported". An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location ..."

I remembered when I had originally installed Sitecore 9.0.1 I had to add the following to the maengine.exe.config & XConnectSearchIndexer.exe.config files; which had been overwritten when I upgraded to 9.0.2.
Adding the following line to the  node in maengine.exe.config & XConnectSearchIndexer.exe.config resolved the issue for me:

`<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />`

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue even while I don't reminder needing this setting before.

Comment: I did a little more investigation. Basically this is caused because the file is downloaded from the internet and I didn't unblock the files yet. 

From the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/loadfromremotesources-element

If an application has been copied from the web, it is flagged by Windows as being a web application, even if it resides on the local computer. You can change that designation by changing its file properties, or you can use the <loadFromRemoteSources>